# Analysis of "Liberty Tree" by Thomas Paine

Tags: meaning, poetry, thomas-paine

I am having some trouble comprehending a portion of "[Liberty Tree](http://thomaspaine.org/essays/poetry/liberty-tree.html)" by Thomas Paine, and was unable to find a decent analysis of it. It is my understanding that this poem is about the [Liberty Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_Tree) that was located in Boston where the [Sons of Liberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sons_of_Liberty) met in order to plan (it died in 1923, and is now memorialized by a statue).

Specifically this stanza:

> In a chariot of light, from the regions of the day,
> The Goddess of Liberty came,
> Ten thousand celestials directed her way,
> And hither conducted the dame.
> A fair budding branch from the gardens above,
> Where millions with millions agree,
> She brought in her hand as a pledge of her love,
> And the plant she named Liberty Tree.

Also, is this reference to timber about the pine which was supplied by the colonies to make masts for their ships?

> Beneath this fair tree, like the patriarchs of old,
> Their bread in contentment they ate,
> Unvexed with the troubles of silver or gold,
> The cares of the grand and the great.
> With timber and tar they Old England supplied,
> And supported her power on the sea;
> Her battles they fought, without getting a groat,
> For the honor of Liberty Tree.

What is really confusing me is specific lines within each stanza. Allow me to provide one example.

> And hither conducted the dame.
> A fair budding branch from the gardens above,
> Where millions with millions agree,

What exactly does this mean? I can understand the overall meaning of the individual stanzas, but certain points confuse me. Even with my researching the definitions.

Comment: The first fragment describes the origin of the tree - brought by the [Liberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_(personification)) from the heavens. Second simply says that people (in America) were giving all they could for Old England without getting anything back.

Comment: My question was poorly worded, and I did not accurately communicate my points of confusion. I suppose what is really confusing me is specific lines within each stanza. Allow me to provide on example.

"And hither conducted the dame.
A fair budding branch from the gardens above,
Where millions with millions agree,"

What exactly does this mean? I can understand the overall meaning of the individual stanzas, but certain points confuse me. Even with my researching the definitions. @Yasskier

Comment: And towards this place they managed/directed themselves towards, this Lady Liberty and her Liberty Tree, from above the liberty tree, Americans, being represented as a " fair branch", all agreed...